# Pandas set labeling legend from groupby elements

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting a kde distribution of 2 dataframes on the same axis, and I need to set a legend saying which line is which dataframe. Now, this is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))

for label, df in dataframe1.groupby('ID'):
     dataframe1.Value.plot(kind="kde", ax=ax,color='r')
for label, df in dataframe2.groupby('ID'):
    dataframe2.Value.plot(kind='kde', ax=ax, color='b')
plt.legend()
plt.title('title here', fontsize=20)
plt.axvline(x=np.pi,color='gray',linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel('mmHg', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

But the result is this:[image]

How can I show the legends inside the graph as 'values from df1' and 'results from df2'?

Edit:
with the following code I correctly have the question's result. But in some dataframes I get the following results:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
sns.kdeplot(akiPEEP['Value'], color="r", label='type 1', ax=ax)
sns.kdeplot(noAkiPEEP['Value'], color="b",label='type 2', ax=ax)
plt.legend()
plt.title('d', fontsize=20)
plt.axvline(x=np.pi,color='gray',linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel('value', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]

A distribution I'm plotting now:

How do I fix this? Also, is it good to also plot the rolling means over this distribution or it becomes too heavy?

Comment: You're plotting each dataframe hundreds of times. Remove the for-loop.

Comment: I need to perform a for loop because I'm plotting all the values of each ID for each dataframe and store them in a kde distribution. Is there a way to modify the legend?

Comment: You are plotting the same dataframe several times. That's why you have so many identical labels in the legend. Again, remove the for-loop, it serves no purpose here.

Comment: ok. Done, I have the same result. But why some dataframes are being plotted as series of kde?

Comment: In the updated plot you have two series (`akiPEEP['Value']` and `noAkiPEEP['Value']`) and each of those two is shown as a KDE curve in a different color. You have as many KDE curves as you have series. This seems the desired output, but if it's not, please explain what you would expect to be different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but from your code, it looks like you are trying to plot one KDE per `ID` value in your dataframes. In which case you would have to do:

```
for label, df in dataframe1.groupby('ID'):
     df.Value.plot(kind="kde", ax=ax,color='r', label=label)
```

notice that I replaced `dataframe1` by `df` in the body of the for-loop. `df` correspond to the sub-dataframe where all the elements in the column `ID` have value `label`